# Django Model become huge

Tags: django, database, django-models

In my project few models has many fields like more than 25. Like i have a model name PeriodOfStay. and it fields are like

- date_of_entry
- i94_number
- port_of_entry
- city ....etc (please check the image for all field)
- also it has many boolean fields . in one form user can multiple options.
- most of the fields are optional.

[image: form image]

so i am confused should i put all the fields in one model. Is it best practice. I don't want split one model to more and use OneToOne Relation cause in that case i need to break up many models cause most of the models in my project are like this also i need to send all data at once in a single request.

I just need to save data and show data to user. in some case i need to search by some field . Like in this form i need to search by i94_number.
Is using JsonField is ok for this problem cause i need to search & filter in some case.

I appreciate any help. Advance Thanks For Help.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question about when to use one-to-one relations:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15405

I think a JsonField is not what you want if you want to search & filter based on some fields. Keeping it in normal fields will make it faster

Some related resource that might be interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: so should i pull all the fields in one model if use one to one relation i need to join many table cause i need to send all the data in every request.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).